# Conditional lambda in pandas returns ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In a df comprised of the columns `asset_id, event_start_date, event_end_date`,
I wish to add a forth column `datediff` that for each `asset_id` will capture how many days passed between a `end_date` and the following `start_date` for the same `asset_id`, but in case that following `start_date` is earlier than the current `end_date`, I would like to capture the difference between the two start_dates. Dataset is sorted by (asset_id, start_date asc).

In Excel it would look something like:

[image]

I tried:

```
  events['datediff'] = df.groupby('asset_id').apply(lambda x:  x['event_start_date'].shift(-1)-x['event_end_date'] if
    x['event_start_date'].shift(-1)>x['event_end_date'] else  x['event_start_date'].shift(-1)-x['event_start_date'] ).\
        fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But this is:

1. not working. Throwing `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`
2. so un-elegant.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you copy and paste that data into your question instead of using a photo

Comment: Write this as an example that we can copy/paste and use to write a working example. This whole post-a-screenshot thing has become a plague.

Comment: The posted code is not valid syntax. Make sure that the demo script you post generates the error you see.

Comment: When you do a comparison on a Series (column) (e.g. `>`) the result is a boolean series, with True or False for each element of the Series.  That can't be used in an `if` expression.  Python `if` expects a simple, scalar True/False, not multiple.  It does not 'iterate' through the boolean series.

Comment: I thought that the lambda runs on every row at a time and return a scalar.  I see now, and it helps me understand the fundamentals better. Thanks @hpaulj !

Comment: There's an `apply` method that will iterate on the rows, applying the function to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'asset_id':[0,0,1,1],
    'event_start_date':['2019-07-08','2019-07-11','2019-07-15','2019-07-25'],
    'event_end_date':['2019-07-08','2019-07-23','2019-07-29','2019-07-25']
                  })

df['event_end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_end_date'])
df['event_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_start_date'])


df['next_start']=df.groupby('asset_id')['event_start_date'].shift(-1)

df['date_diff'] = np.where(
    df['next_start']>df['event_end_date'],
    (df['next_start']-df['event_end_date']).dt.days,
    (df['next_start']-df['event_start_date']).dt.days
        )

df = df.drop(columns=['next_start']).fillna(0)
```